# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum' pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame in Pandas...

```
+-----------------------+
|              | count  |
+-----------------------+
| group        |        |
+-----------------------+
| 11-          | 99435  |
+-----------------------+
| Bachelor+    | 64900  |
+-----------------------+
| Just 12      | 162483 |
+-----------------------+
| Some College | 61782  |
+-----------------------+
```

I want to perform the following code but I'm getting an error...

```
death_2013['percent_of_total'] = death_2013.count.apply(
     lambda x: (x / death_2013.count.sum()))
```

I'm getting the following error...

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

I checked the `death_2013.dtypes` and `count` is a int64. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: count is the column name. I can either do `death_2013.count.apply` or `death_2013['count'].apply` but none of them seems to work. What is weird is that I have this very line of code working with different data set.

Comment: The error message suggests that it is a function object

Comment: Why not `death_2013['count'].apply()`?

Comment: OMG!!! seems like `count` is a reserved word in pandas or python. I change the column name and now `apply()` is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`pandas.DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) method, which is shadowing the name of your column. This is why you're getting this error message - the bound method `count` is being accessed, which then obviously doesn't work.

In this case, you should simply use the `['name_of_column']` syntax to access the `count` column in both places, and be mindful of DataFrame method names when naming columns in the future.

```
death_2013['percent_of_total'] = death_2013['count'].apply(
    lambda x: (x / death_2013['count'].sum()))
```

Note however that in this particular case there is no need to use `apply` - you can simply divide the entire Series by the mean.

```
death_2013['count'] / death_2013['count'].sum()
```

Comment: I rather change variable name. I figure it out right before your solution. Thank you for confirming what I suspect.

Comment: @Gilbert You're welcome! It is one of the downsides of using that syntax, along with trying to set a new column.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that dataframes have a `count` method. If you want to run `apply()` on a columns named `count` use the syntax

```
death_2013['count'].apply()
```

Alternatively, rename the column.